# Xcode Cocoapod Library not loading

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I published my app to the app store a month ago.  Now I made a few UI fixes and it works fine on the simulator but when I try to run it on my phone I get this error...

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/88C2E647-66A2-4C03-895A-C5DD947713F5/STCR.app/STCR
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

If I take Alamofire out it simply moves down to the next framework in my Podfile.

Comment: Have you tried clean the project and the derived data?

Comment: Yup multiple times - no beans.

Comment: Look this, and see if it helps.
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/101